# how do i select where status = 0 and not both with laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to select info from a DB::table using the following example

```
Table::where('status', 1)
      ->where('senderid', myid)
     ->orWhere('recevrid', myid)
     ->get();
```

i want This script to select rows where status=1 but its also returning results where the status is even zero..
Can you help with a way where i can make it only select where status = 1 and 0

Comment: how many status are there ? execpt 0,1

Comment: status is a column in table and its boolean data type with 0 as default and value of 1 if updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nesting query like this

```
$query = Table::where('status', 1);
$query->where(function($query) use($myid){
    $query->orWhere('senderid', $myid);
    $query->orWhere('recevrid', $myid);
});
$result = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Table::where([['status','=', 1],['senderid','=', myid]])
     ->orWhere([['status','=', 1],['recevrid','=', myid]])
     ->get();
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. It'll also select the records where receiverID is equal to myId without looking at the status flag.